# Entity Framework RetryLazy`2 Object Reference Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I'm getting an object reference error on some very simple code:

```
private void LoadJobs(int? selectedJobID = null)
{
  using (var db = new ERP3Entities())
  {
    incompleteJobs = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.Complete == false).ToArray();
  }
}
```

incompleteJobs is an array used elsewhere in the class.  The code works fine when I run it in my dev environment and works fine most the time in production.  But users sometimes get object reference errors.  I'm using EF 6.1.3 Code First.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace:   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at SaveParts.TaskManagerTab.LoadJobs(Nullable`1 selectedJobID)
at SaveParts.TaskManagerTab.LoadData(IModelDoc2 doc) 
at SaveParts.AssemblyEventHandler.RegenPostNotify2(Object stopFeature)
```